# Выводит на консоль символы вместо кириллицы.

Tags: c#

[image: Скрин моей проблемы]

Хотелось бы навсегда решить эту проблему, а то для ее лечения я каждый раз вставляю это //Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8

Comment: `OutputEncoding` — это и есть единственное правильное решение. Извне это не решить.

Comment: Выполните в консоли команду `chcp` и скопируйте сюда то, что она написала.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko http://firepic.org/images/2015-09/14/ldurado72sjx.png

Comment: Фотохостинг почему то не показывает страницу. По большому счёту, скриншот и не нужен, там в выводе команды должен быть номер кодовой страницы, вроде 866, 1251, 65001 — его достаточно.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko я обновил ссылку, но в любом случае Вы правы. 437

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ситуация обстоит следующим образом: в качестве кодировки по умолчанию в вашей системе установлена 437. Это стандартная кодировка, разработанная в IBM для самых первых персоналок IBM PC предназначенных для США; в целях совместимости дожившая до наших времён. Она содержит только символы английского алфавита и некоторые греческие буквы. Она не содержит символы европейских языков (с умляутами и штрихами), и тем более не содержит символов кириллицы.

Так что, похоже, у Вас американская либо международная версия Windows.

Для того, чтобы показывать русский текст (кириллицу) необходимо переключиться на кодировку 866 (DOS), 1251 (Windows) или 65001 (UTF-8). Последняя кодировка универсальнее, поскольку позволяет показывать также и символы других алфавитов, не только русского и английского.

Вы можете переключить язык даже в английской версии Windows с помощью команды `chcp`.

Однако, это не всегда помогает, поскольку для отображения Unicode-символов необходим шрифт, содержащий глифы для этих символов. То есть помимо кодовой страницы для консоли необходимо установить также шрифт, например Lucida Console, вместо Terminal.

В любом случае, установка шрифтов и кодовой страницы — прерогатива всё-таки пользователя компьютера, а не разработчика программы. Разработчик (то есть Вы) со своей стороны можете сделать следующее:

1. Вынести текст всех сообщений в отдельный файл ресурсов.
2. В этом файле подготовить все сообщения на английском языке. Это будут ресурсы по умолчанию.
3. Подготовить второй файл ресурсов, куда сохранить сообщения на русском языке.

После этого в английской, международной и прочих не-русских версиях программа будет показывать сообщения на английском. В русской версии Windows, где выбрана культура ru-ru и установлена кодировка CP1251 или CP65001 — программа будет выводить сообщения на русском.

Пользователи-французы, итальянцы, японцы — смогут подготовить ресурсы на своём языке, переведя их с английского. Эти ресурсы могут быть *скомпилированы* в DLL. Если скопировать эту DLL в каталог программы, она будет показывать сообщения например на итальянском в итальянской версии Windows. Замечу, что для этого не нужно иметь исходного кода Вашей программы, и вообще, от Вас не потребуется ничего — пользователю потребуется EXE или DLL с текстами по-умолчанию, чтобы сделать свой перевод этих текстов.

Выбор английского в качестве языка по умолчанию хорош тем, что этот язык по историческим причинам поддерживается всеми версиями Windows (и не только Windows).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Замечательный ресурс с замечательными людьми!!

Answer (score 6):

Сам файл "program.cs" сохраняется по умолчанию в UTF-8, а кодировка консоли обычно chcp 1251 поэтому такая проблема.

Можно сменить кодировку консоли по умолчанию и тогда не придется в коде ничего писать, однако на другой машине проблема опять даст о себе знать, поэтому как уже сказали в комментарии, единственное правильное решение это

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
```

Comment: Был бы рад узнать как это сделать.

Comment: строки в .net всегда в unicode, так что прописывание левой кодировки файла проблему не решит (точнее, выводится они будут, возможно и правильно, но в рантайме будут кракозяблы)

Comment: Боюсь показать свою глупость, но на предыдущей системе я не приходил к таким манипуляциям. Поставил 10 и вот те на. Я все же думаю, что есть вариант вернуть прежнюю спокойную работу без перехода на 7-ку.

Comment: @IgorYarovoy у меня 10-ка, в консоли по умолчанию работает unicode

Comment: Выражаю благодарность!

Answer (score 4):

Если нужен просто вывод русских букв, то поменяйте у себя язык по умолчанию для не-юникодных программ:

Control Panel / Region / Administrative tab / Change System Locale. Выберите там Russian.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это аналогично ручному вызову `chck 866`. Скорее всего эта настройка была включена у вас в 7-ке. Странно, что слетела при апгрейде.

Если нужен именно Unicode (`chcp 65001`), то можно задать его как кодовую страницу по умолчанию в реестре. Честно [скопировано с enSO](https://superuser.com/a/927575/292032):

Reg file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"CodePage"=dword:fde9
```

Command Prompt

```
REG ADD HKCU\Console /v CodePage /t REG_DWORD /d 0xfde9
```

PowerShell

```
sp -t d HKCU:\Console CodePage 0xfde9
```

Cygwin

```
regtool set /user/Console/CodePage 0xfde9
```

Но все это сработает только на вашей машине. так что лучше на всякий случай писать

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас!!!