# Вместо русских букв знак вопроса. Как исправить?

Tags: c#, json

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserMatch>(File.ReadAllText("../../../test.json"));

    foreach (var i in test?.info?.participants) {
        if (i.summonerName == command.Data.Options.First().Value.ToString())
        {
            if (i.win == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Поражение");
            }
            else if (i.win == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Победа");
            }
        }
    }
```

Получаю значит JSON файл и вместо русских букв внутри него ???? из-за этого проверка через if не понимает (например никнейм призывателя "привет", а  сравнивает он с ?????)

Comment: Какая ОС? В какой кодировке файл?

Comment: @CrazyElf Проблема не в ОС, а как это будет компилироваться. Как итог if не может сравнить с русскими буквами

Comment: От ОС зависит то, в какой кодировке программа ожидает получить `JSON`. И эта кодировка может не совпадать с той кодировкой, в которой у вас записан `JSON` файл. Вы бы не спорили лучше, а добавили всю информацию. И попробовали совет из ответа - вдруг да поможет. Но там нужно указать кодировку, в которой у вас реально записан файл. Может он в `UTF-8`, а прога ожидает `cp1251`, как знать.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/450592/373567, https://stackoverflow.com/q/388490/12888024

Answer (score 0):

Надо указать кодировку:

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserMatch>(File.ReadAllText("../../../test.json", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)));
```

Либо же поменять кодировку файла на utf-8
Больше о кодировках, можно узнать в документации: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding?view=net-7.0

Comment: Откуда вы вообще взяли что данные в 1251?

Comment: Эникейство оно такое .. попробуйте то-се пока не получится, а почему получилось - а не важно ))

Comment: @Kromster Предлагать попробовать вообще нормально, но в комментариях, а не сразу в ответе )

Comment: @CrazyElf согласен. Минус не мой, если что, т.к. хоть это и плохой ответ, но все же не совсем бесполезный.

Comment: Почему кодировка 1251? Потому что в документации написано, что 1251 служит для отображения кириллицы

Comment: @Artiom не важно для чего служит 1251 (она кстати устарела и умерла уже), важно - в какой кодировке данные и сама консоль. Совет поменять кодировку файла хороший, а вот то что до него - так себе.