# C# Консоль не выводит стринговую переменную с русским текстом (а по-русски писать может)

Tags: c#, кодировка

я полный новичок.
Поменяла ноутбук, консоль вначале вместо кириллицы писала вопросительные знаки, я вроде бы разобралась, теперь она пишет на кириллице, но если я задаю переменную, в которой кириллица, она ее не выводит (просто пустое место и довольная с кодом 0 заканчивает). А если в эту же переменную я пишу текст латиницей, то выводит.

Comment: А какая операционная система?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450613/373567

Comment: Window 11. Знаете,я справилась, если в коде вначале написать Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode, а не UTF8, то работает